# How come CSS cant find image?

Tags: css

I am using nivo slider with the below setup

[image]

```
/
    /js
        /nivo
            /images
                 ...
            nivo-slider.css
            ...
```

In nivo-slider.css, dont I reference images using "images/bullets.png"? But in the browser, I dont see images, then in firebug, it says not found too...

Comment: if you use textmate then drag your arrow.png image to your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it was a Linux permissions thingy... after chmod to 755 it works ...

Answer (score 3):

The path is relative to the current page. That is, if you are in `/index.htm`, your path points to `/images/bullet.png`. Use an absolute path:

```
background:url("/js/nivo/images/bullets.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

In Firebug mouse over where it say not found, it should show the full path and check with that path in directory is correct or not and change if required.
Most probably, you are calling the CSS from other file where the it points to different path.

If required use the full path (not recommended always).

Comment: I'd remove the "not" from your last sentence. Using absolute paths solves all sorts of problems and running a web server on your development machine isn't a problem anymore.